# Apply Hover on the Nested Class Navigation

Tags: css, sass

I have a mock up sample code below that displays a nested sub menu on my project

```css
.navigation {
    .cmp-navigation {
        .cmp-navigation__group {
            .cmp-navigation__item--level-0 {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 10px;

                .cmp-navigation__item-link {
                    color: red;
                }

                .cmp-navigation__group {
                   position: absolute;
                   display: block;

                    .cmp-navigation__item--level-1 {
                        .cmp-navigation__item-link {
                            color: yellow;
                        }

                        .cmp-navigation__group {
                            left: 100%;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0px;
         
                            .cmp-navigation__item--level-2 {
                                .cmp-navigation__item-link {
                                    color: orange;
                                }
                            }
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

.navigation {
    .cmp-navigation {
        .cmp-navigation__group {
            .cmp-navigation__item--level-0 {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 10px;

                .cmp-navigation__item-link {
                    color: red;
                }

                .cmp-navigation__group {
                   position: absolute;
                   display: block;

                    .cmp-navigation__item--level-1 {
                        .cmp-navigation__item-link {
                            color: yellow;
                        }

                        .cmp-navigation__group {
                            left: 100%;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0px;
         
                            .cmp-navigation__item--level-2 {
                                .cmp-navigation__item-link {
                                    color: orange;
                                }
                            }
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

.cmp-navigation__item--level-1 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12">
         <nav class="cmp-navigation" role="navigation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
            <ul class="cmp-navigation__group">
               <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-0">
                  <a href="" title="Home" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-0">
                  <a href="" title="Equipments" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Equipments</a>
                  <ul class="cmp-navigation__group">
                     <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-1">
                        <a href="" title="Trucks" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Trucks</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-1">
                        <a href="" title="Woods" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Woods</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
```

And the output is something like this

[image: Sample Output]

The code above works fine but my problem is how to apply the hover on sub menu. My target for this nested view is to apply the hide and show on hover. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to hide the submenu items using `display: none`. Then you need to add `:hover` to the parent of the submenu to change from `display: none` to `display: block`. Here's an example.

```css
nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12">
  <nav class="cmp-navigation" role="navigation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <ul class="cmp-navigation__group">
      <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-0">
        <a href="" title="Home" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-0">
        <a href="" title="Equipments" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Equipments</a>
        <ul class="cmp-navigation__group">
          <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-1">
            <a href="" title="Trucks" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Trucks</a>
          </li>
          <li class="cmp-navigation__item cmp-navigation__item--level-1">
            <a href="" title="Woods" data-cmp-clickable class="cmp-navigation__item-link">Woods</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `li>ul>li` would make more sense if there's multiple levels of submenus